# jshint in visual studio code - Server initialization failed

Tags: visual-studio-code, jshint

I'm getting the following error message in the output window of Visual studio code for the jshint extension.

`[Error - 08:38:27] Server initialization failed.
  Message: Request initialize failed with message: missing ) after argument list
  Code: -32603`

I'm guessing this is an error in the .jshintrc file. I haven't added a .jshintrc file so I assume it's being found somewhere or using a default value.
Any suggestions on how to fix or track down the error?